# rails error message String can't be coerced into Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, loops

I'm trying to make variable in .each do loop.

```
<article class='lecture-list' >
    <% @lectures.each do |lecture| %>
      <div class='lecture-list-wrapper'>

        <p class='activity'>
            <% name = lecture.id + "th - "+ lecture.title %>
            <span><%= link_to name, lecture, class: 'btn-lightgreen' %></span>
            <span><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_lecture_path(lecture), class: 'btn-darkyellow' %></span>
            <span><%= link_to 'Destroy', lecture, method: :delete, class: 'btn-darkorange', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></span></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
</article>
```

`<% name = lecture.id + "th - "+ lecture.title %>` part makes

> String can't be coerced into Fixnum

error. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

`<% name = lecture.id + "th - "+ lecture.title %>`

Try:
Note: If you want it as variable, ideally use `_` underscore not `-` dash. As code below.

`<% name = lecture.id.to_s + "th_"+ lecture.title %>`

Answer (score 0):

OJ1987 answer is fine, though I prefer using interpolation in such cases:

```
<% name = "#{lecture.id}th - #{lecture.title}" %>
```